# What could be the reason for returning null value in json from FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the data as json and I want to print it on FutureBuilder but no matter what I do the json data appearing on print is not listed in FutureBuilder. FutureBuilder returns null. What could be the reason for this?

*payment_model.dart*

```dart
Future<List<PaymentData>> paymentGetList() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  dynamic responseData;
  String token = await getToken();
  final paymentListApiUrl = Uri.parse(
      apiUrlKey + preferences.getString('apiUrl').toString() + paymentListUrl);

try {

  final response = await http.post(paymentListApiUrl, headers: {
    'Authorization': token,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  }, body: {
      'filters': '',
      'params': '',
      'limit': '10',
      'offset': '0',
      'sorting': ''
    });

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var jsonArray = jsonData['data'];
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> map = [];
    map = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(jsonArray);
    responseData = map;
  }

} catch (e) {

  print("Buradayız:  $e");

}

  return responseData;
}
```

FutureBuilder

```
FutureBuilder<List<PaymentData>>(
  future: paymentGetList(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot) {
  var data = AsyncSnapshot.data;
  print(data);
  if (data == null) {
    return const Text('No Data');
  } else {
    return const Text('Yes Data');
  }}),

//The result for me is null here
```

When I print on Payment_model.dart, I get the following result.

```
[{id: 1, paymentsend_id: , collection_email: 0, collection_sms: 0, period_order: 0, email: mail@site.com, card_type1: cardfinans, card_type2: troy, card_name_surname: asktest, comment: , NULL: , customer_id: 123, orderid: 123123321, installment_number: 3, plus_installment: , status: 3D-POST, masked_card: 111111** **** 1111, total_with_commison: 1000.0000, total_without_commison: 1000.0000, currency_type: null, transaction_data: , transaction_bank: ing, transaction_type: 2, partial: , name_surname: asktest, phone_number: 1233123123, post_code: , city: Gaziantep, district: sahinbey, country: TR, payment_type: 3d, member_code: , payment_note: , payment_address: , erp_order_ids: , erp_status: , erp_status_msg: , id_number: , tax_number: , payment_ip: 111.111.11.11, space1: 12/2024, space2: , space3: , space4: log, space5: null, space6: null, space7: null, pos_id: null, created_in: 2021-11-26 12:54:07, updated_in: 0000-00-00 00:00:00}..]
```

Comment: One thing that's wrong is that you say your function returns a `List<PaymentData>` but actually returns a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`. make sure to return the right type

Comment: How can I use it as List<PaymentData>? I don't know where I went wrong. @Ivo

Comment: Nowhere you convert your response to `PaymentData`. I don't know what that class looks like but I suppose it maybe has something like `fromJson` or `fromMap` that you need to use, and if it doesn't have that you need to create it.

Comment: i think your code no problem.  response status code is not 200 .  but not error
so its not catch as error.  you have to add else condition to debug why  responseData =null

Comment: @Ivo PaymentData.fromMap(jsonArray); I get the error "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>". I tried to try different ways as I couldn't solve this error.

Comment: `print(AsyncSnapshot)` what do you see?

Comment: I strongly suggest you forget the `dynamic` keyword exists. Use proper types for all your variables and your compiler will guide you through it. If you flat out lie to your compiler by using `dynamic` it has no chance to help you and you will be stuck.